# Does a limited bandwidth homespot affect the bandwidth of my personal network?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, wireless-access-point

I have 4 networks at home: a 5 GHz network and a 2.4 Ghz network from my own router, a 2.4 Ghz network from the router/modem of my ISP and another 2.4 Ghz homespot from my ISP, intended for other customers of the ISP to use if they have enabled their own homespot. The ISP Homespot has a very low bandwidth (around 1 Mbps according to speedtest.net) and they claim that it does not affect the performance of my own network.

However, my uncle recently said that such a homespot DOES reduce the performance of the network, and that some users might even get onto his local system by using that homespot, even if he is not connected to the homespot himself. As such, he disabled it on his own router (which also disabled his access to other homespots).

Personally, I think that my uncle is overestimating the impact by a few orders of magnitude. I think the only ways it can impact the performance is A) through wifi interference from the signal, and B) because it needs to go through the same cable to the outside world as his own connections. Even so, I doubt that the impact could be more than a few %. and those security risks he mentioned seem ridiculous to me.

Comment: Do you have 4 separate networks (as in 4 WiFi SSID's all broadcasting) or do you 1 WiFi router that's hooked into your ISP provided WiFi router that are both just providing access to the 2.4/5GHz channels?

Comment: @txtechhelp My ISP router is connected to the outside and broadcasts a customer wifi for me and a public wifi homespot for any outsiders. my own router is connected to the ISP and broadcasts the 2 other networks. They all have their own network name and are all different networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Dutch is limited (read: non-existant), and I couldn't find a good Google translate of the [Telenet WiFi](http://telenet.be/nl/wi-free) site to get info (user related and technical) on the 'homespot' capability. I could make out enough to see that it's on the DOCSIS 3.0 standard, which means high bandwidth capabilities (plenty of room for a 1Mb WiFi link), that being said I also couldn't find a lot of info (that I could understand) as to 'how' the WiFi homespot is actually technically and physically setup, but chances are it's very similar to the US Comcast homespot since the homespot functionality for Comcast started in their EU unit, where I'm sure the Comcast EU homespot probably (at least techincally) mimic's how the Telenet homespot operates. If this is the case (technically speaking it probably is), then this 'homespot' capability shouldn't disrupt or interact with your network.

Technically what is happening is the ISP provided modem most likely communicates back with the ISP to let them 'know' if the homespot ability is 'enabled', if so, they probably flash/update the modem to allow it to bond to enough/other channels to support the bandwidth you are paying for in addition to the homespot bandwidth they are allocating thus not interfering with each others allotted 'minimums' (as long as they are on different channels).

You are correct in thinking the WiFi interference could be a potential issue, but if you have the WiFi channel setting on both WiFi AP's to be 'auto' (or at least far enough away from each other on the channels) they shouldn't interfere with each others signal, at least no more so than the other 20 WiFi signals in your proximity.

As for the homespot using the same wire to transmit data, yes this COULD cause slowdown, but no more so than your neighbor 5 houses up the block who likes to stream and download 24/7; at least in theory, in practice you'd have to do some independent testing because of how telco's can wire certain area's, but if the homespot 'connection' is on a different channel(s) on the actual wire then it shouldn't interfere with your connections.

As for other users being able to access 'your' network 'through' the homespot router, well that all depends. I don't know how the 'homespot' is technically setup (i.e. through the modem and back to your ISP), but chances are the modem is just (technically) acting as a ISP wireless gateway that just happens to be on the same physical equipment that you have your internet link through. If that's the case then anyone using the homespot would have the same access to your internal network as the rest of the internet. An easy way to test this is to connect to the homespot WiFi and compare IP scheme's then run some simple tests to see if you can access your home network (via outward facing IP and internal IP schemes).

If the homespot router is only acting as a sort of ISP WiFi gateway, it *can* introduce another possible attack vector over just normal internet access. If the firmware that runs the homespot WiFi router is found to have some sort of bug in it, there ***MIGHT*** (notice big might) be a chance that an attacker could leverage the homespot AP and tunnel through the router itself into your other (personal) network; but to pull this off would require more time/effort than any (reasonable) hacker would dedicate to try and hack joe schmoe nobody over just finding some other open WiFi point and attacking that.

TLDR; your uncle is technically incorrect in his assessments of both bandwidth usage and physical/logical access to the internally separated networks of the homespot functionality.

Mind you this is all assuming best case scenario setups of the equipment and YMMV.

Hope that can help.

Comment: I'm not in the US, I'm in Belgium. My ISP is Telenet, one of the biggest players on the market and a really good one.

Comment: Modified the answer to be indifferent to ISP as the 'homespot' functionality operates (at a technical level) relatively the same.